# Activate plugin depending on packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I would like to write a plugin and add the execution in the parent pom. But the plugin should only be active if the packaging (of the child project) is "ejb".

Is there a way to do that?

I know that activating/deactivating profiles depending on the packaging is not possible. I furthermore read that you can define your own lifecycles and attach them to packaging, but this seems to be too complicated.

The workaround I am thinking about is to add a check at the beginning of the plugin, but then you would always have an entry in in the log like "Starting xy-plugin, xy-plugin skipped because packaging is not ejb".

The actual use-case: We have a plugin that generates default bindings for WebSphere and should only be generated for ejbs.

Comment: I would suggest to create a packaging `websphereejb` and make it that way..otherwise it's not really possible...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would need to write a component.xml for that. Do you have any reference for writing such a file?

Answer (score 0):

Define a field like this in your Maven plugin:

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.packaging}", required = true)
protected String packaging;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I described as "workaround" in the question. Furthermore, newer Maven versions now allow to activate a profile based on packaging.

Comment: Could you provide some code demonstrating this?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Implicit_profile_activation contains "Since Maven 3.9.0 one can also evaluate the POM's packaging value by referencing property packaging"